# A check if username exist in database with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to make a small project with python since I just started learning that.
I'm using MySQL, and I have 3 tables inside my database, ID, username and password.
I'm trying to get from stdin a username and password and check if they already exist inside my database.
What I tried so far is :

```
def login():
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()
  print('Enter username: ')
  username = input()
  checkUsername = mycursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?', (username))
  if checkUsername != 0:
    print('Username is not exist')
  else:
    print('Logged In!')
```

but I'm getting an error which says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What if you try a ```SELECT users.username FROM users WHERE users.username=?```

Comment: @JordyCuan that did'nt work.

Comment: What is the total usercase? i assume it is:  checking if the username exists and insert when it not exists and or update when it exists more or less?  If that the case you should be adding a UNIQUE key in MySQL table to prevent race conditions..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm just trying to check if the username is exist in the table, if yes check if password for this username is correct. I dont want to add if not.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
checkUsername = mycursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?', (username))
```

with

```
checkUsername = mycursor.execute(
'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = %(username)s', { 'username' : username })
```

or with

```
checkUsername = mycursor.execute(
'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = %(username)s', (username,))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to use mycursor.fetchone() or mycursor.fetchall() in order to get the selceted items in database
other than that, the error you are getting is because of wrong syntax, when placing variables outside the query using the ? placeholder you need to replace this `(username))` with this `(username,))`, 
try something like that:

```
def login():
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()
  print('Enter username: ')
  username = input()
  mycursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?', (username,))
  checkUsername = mycursor.fetchone()
  if checkUsername != 0:
    print('Username does not exist')
  else:
    print('Logged In!')
```